# Given $P(\sqrt2)$ = $13+9\sqrt2$, then find $\frac{P(1)}{4}$

Tags: polynomials

My Question is-

> Let $P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and $a_i \in \{0,1\}$ for all $i = 0,1,2,\cdots,n$. Given $P(\sqrt2) = 13+9\sqrt2$, then find $\frac{P(1)}{4}$.

I can't understand what to do with this question. Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $$P(\sqrt2)=\left(\sum_{j} a_{2j}2^j\right)+\sqrt2\left(\sum_ka_{2k+1}2^k\right).$$

Comment: Plug in $\sqrt{2}$ for $x$ and then separate out even and odd powers of $\sqrt{2}$. Then think binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the coefficients are 0 and 1, then we can solve it by writing 13 and 9 in binary, and respectively using 0s in 1s in the appropriate even and odd terms (since the even terms give an integer in binary, and the odd terms do as well but multiplied by $\sqrt{2}$.

Explicitly, $13 = 8 + 4 + 1 = \sqrt{2}^6 + \sqrt{2}^{4} + \sqrt{2}^0$, and $9\sqrt{2} = 8\sqrt{2} + 1\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}^7 +\sqrt{2}^1$. So the coefficients we use are $i=0,1,4,6,7$.

So the polynomial is just $$P(x) = 1 + x + x^4 + x^6 + x^7$$

Hence $P(1)= 5$ so $$ \boxed{\frac{P(1)}{4} = \frac{5}{4}}$$

One can see after the fact that since we're substituting one, it would have sufficed to just count the sum of the number of 1s in the binary representations of $9$ and $13$.

Comment: Thanks for the help.